# wifi connected internet disconnected

Tags: wireless, internet, 16.10, atheros

**Laptop:** Lenovo G50-45

**Processor:** AMD E1 processor

**Wifi:** Qualcomm Atheros built-in wifi.

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.10

**Problem:** Stays connected to the wireless router, however, the internet stops working.

---

**Workaround**

1. Disconnect from my Wi-fi
2. Reconnect

Works for another 5 minutes and then I have to repeat the above steps.

---

Ping request returns

```
From xxxxxx-Lenovo-G50-45 (192.168.0.6) icmp_seq=999 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Output of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 20
       serial: c8:ff:28:ca:c5:79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.8.0-32-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:39 memory:f0800000-f09fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 50:7b:9d:c4:30:f5
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0c04000-f0c04fff memory:f0c00000-f0c03fff
```

---

`ifconfig` details when connected

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xxxxx(masked)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 50367  bytes 3271419 (3.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50367  bytes 3271419 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 xxxxx(masked)  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xxxxx(masked)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58474  bytes 59035701 (59.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37687  bytes 5854176 (5.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ifconfig` details when not internet is not working

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xxxxx(masked)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 248144  bytes 15440577 (15.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 248144  bytes 15440577 (15.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 xxxxx(masked)  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xxxxx(masked)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 98559  bytes 101523293 (101.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63919  bytes 9217006 (9.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**EDIT:**

Results of `iwconfig`

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"AbyNabs"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 90:8D:78:F7:05:5D   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2197  Invalid misc:3733   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Results of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Comment: Please edit to add results for `iwconfig; cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: Done.  @Jeremy31

Comment: Any chance you are using TLP?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: I doubt you are using it as you would need to install it

Comment: So should I install it? Also, the connection drops are fewer than before...

Answer (score 0):

Your issues may be the result of wireless power management.  We can disable with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know after two days...

Comment: Sorry for a delayed response. It did not work.